How do I change the mirror in a Dockerfile?
I encountered this problem while trying to install FFMPEG on a dockerfile.
# Stage 1: Build stage
FROM node:18 AS builder

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json into the working directory
COPY package*.json ./

# Install all dependencies specified in package.json
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source inside the container
COPY . .

# Build the app
RUN npm run build


# Stage 2: Production stage
FROM node:18 AS production

# Use debian slim for installing ffmpeg
RUN apt-get clean
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN apt-get clean
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade
RUN apt-get install -y ffmpeg

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json
COPY package*.json ./

# Install only production dependencies
RUN npm install --only=production

# Copy the built app from the builder stage
COPY --from=builder /app/dist ./dist

# Expose port 3000
EXPOSE 3000

# Command to run the app
CMD [ "npm", "run", "serve" ]

Here's the error:
http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libx/libxcb/libxcb-dri3-0_1.15-1_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
37.68    Hashes of expected file:
37.68     - SHA256:02699b144b9467de8636d27a76984b8f4e7b66e2d25d96df2b9677be86ee9a29
37.68     - MD5Sum:3008f6b77784f198f7304fa0e3dbe0a3 [weak]
37.68     - Filesize:106676 [weak]
37.68    Hashes of received file:
37.68     - SHA256:05c75d1dbc965c32cd67843859f4195e434657af3af064ec5c918ec1b2bd8411
37.68     - MD5Sum:d89f3aab4bad5dde7943c506d7baec4b [weak]
37.68     - Filesize:106676 [weak]
37.68    Last modification reported: Thu, 04 Aug 2022 06:55:38 +0000
37.68 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/j/jpeg-xl/libjxl0.7_0.7.0-10_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
37.68    Hashes of expected file:
37.68     - SHA256:559b29ce34e1737984f41268c58a8e5e13b88a498c1063ffc500825a63e1b96f
37.68     - MD5Sum:f26de3898c43151fda44a887f90c0b78 [weak]
37.68     - Filesize:1045904 [weak]
37.68    Hashes of received file:
37.68     - SHA256:2fe6756f9e17df6f2a2a0a3b725bdf0b7dd5e85724e2179b34c71303bb1ccc9a
37.68     - MD5Sum:6761021026dc7e3bbf706304bac1a4ca [weak]
37.68     - Filesize:1045904 [weak]
37.68    Last modification reported: Sun, 29 Jan 2023 13:42:47 +0000
37.68 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/svt-av1/libsvtav1enc1_1.4.1%2bdfsg-1_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
37.68    Hashes of expected file:
37.68     - SHA256:e0f6e357f327e80f26438dcda9c9304c43e2f3343359c6a5075d0b10ddfdb05d
37.68     - MD5Sum:12842f2c9bd2085927a7ff89a3350ca7 [weak]
37.68     - Filesize:2121284 [weak]
37.68    Hashes of received file:
37.68     - SHA256:933056d0295626d6217828fce6e0c461ea08189d272c47a7370009f407291030
37.68     - MD5Sum:67efb94064b8a709e958fd1a30402ff2 [weak]
37.68     - Filesize:2121284 [weak]
37.68    Last modification reported: Fri, 16 Dec 2022 21:11:34 +0000
37.68 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libv/libvpx/libvpx7_1.12.0-1%2bdeb12u3_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
37.68    Hashes of expected file:
37.68     - SHA256:e1d195791c680b7901acfd86bc9eb2343dee41ae61c5922630a07bcc4e325693
37.68     - MD5Sum:d65a3d96cace78b6834cdb85e779cf31 [weak]
37.68     - Filesize:1003304 [weak]
37.68    Hashes of received file:
37.68     - SHA256:2cfd67e60b3704bd30e1174cf6721c4d2430d72d4d823d98c976cf923b6372f9
37.68     - MD5Sum:3cbc56f26e04be7f9a14142c2d62c9e8 [weak]
37.68     - Filesize:1003304 [weak]
37.68    Last modification reported: Tue, 25 Jun 2024 20:45:12 +0000
37.68 E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
------
Dockerfile:29
--------------------
  27 |     RUN apt-get update
  28 |     RUN apt-get upgrade
  29 | >>> RUN apt-get install -y ffmpeg
  30 |     
  31 |     # Set the working directory
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y ffmpeg" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100

Based on the research I conducted, this appeared to be a case of a mirror not responding properly. However, based on the dockerfile I have, I don't know how to update the mirrors list to use a different mirror. How do I do that?

does setting the compression to gz work? Failed to fetch ........... Hash Sum mismatch

It does. I attempted a similar approach but hardcoded it for the problematic packages. I perhaps will document my own solution.
